# How to retrieve images faster in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

We are using SQL Server 2014 (not SQL Azure) and I have defined a simple table to store images (.jpg) and

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Graphic](
    [GraphicID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [FileName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [FileDescription] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [Image] [varbinary](max) NULL
)
```

max size of an image stored is 1MB, this validation is taken care on the front-end. I just inserted 15 images and the table size is 5544 KB currently. There is a primary key placed on GraphicID column. No other indexes placed.

But when I retrieve one or more images using the below (simple SELECT) query, it is taking longer time like 25 - 30 seconds.

```
select * from [Graphic]
where [GraphicID] = 53
```

Is there a faster mechanism to query images in SQL Server in less than 5 seconds ?

Is there any alternate SAVE & RETRIEVE mechanism for images in SQL Server 2014 for better performance ?

Please help.

Thanks

Bhanu

Comment: What is the query you are using to retrieve the results? And what indexes do you have on the tables?

Comment: Stop storing images in the database.

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: Google Filestream

Comment: Question updated with more details. Thank you.

Comment: Where is the client (the one doing the query) in relation to the server? I see that you have some `Azure` related questions. If you are fetching over the internet, then network transfer might be the main issue...

Comment: First, yes there is another mechanism, since 2005 - use FILESTREAM to store images outside the database. The times you mention though don't make sense. How fast is your network connection? You can't speed up anything if the *connection* is the problem.

Comment: Do you have an index on `GraphicID` ? The schema you posted doesn't show either a `PRIMARY KEY` or an index. This means that the delay is caused because SQL Server has to search the entire table to find a matching ID. How many rows are in the table?

Comment: @Bhanu your question lacks the fundamental information needed for such questions - indexes and the execution plan. Without them one can only speculate

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Actually OP edited in `There is a primary key placed on GraphicID column.`.

Comment: @user1429080 that's not what the schema shows. A lot of people confuse `IDENTITY` for a primary key. That's why the execution plan is essential. It will show what's slowing things down immediatelly

Comment: @user1429080, thanks for your note, the SQL Server 2014 is a VM in Azure, when I tried to execute the query inside the VM, it ran without any delay. But the query took time when it is run outside the VM.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Graphic](
    [GraphicID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FileName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [FileDescription] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [Image] [varbinary](max) NULL
)
```

If that is indeed your schema (and you seem extremely unsure of it), the problem is that you never added indices to your table. Add a clustered index over `GraphicID` and it should fix this particular access pattern.

Another note would be that if you know the maximum size of your `varbinary` (and you said you do), you should use it rather than using `max`. That way the table layout will store the image inside the row (up to a certain size) rather than appending it at the end, making row retrieval (`select *`) a lot faster for larger, fragmented tables.

Comment: At 5mb size for his table, this would not matter a little bit. It's `varbinary(max)` that is screwing him up.

Comment: No it's not, that only matters when inserting. Selecting it out is relatively fast.

Comment: You can argue, but he has only 15 records in the table. Not 15,000,000.